# How can I encode French characters in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding

I am using Google Translate in French and some letters of result come back to me as some symbols. After some research, I learned it is because of encoding but I need some help because I could not find enough information.

Here is my code:

```
   - (void)performTranslation:(NSString *) inputStr {

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 NSString *outLang = [defaults objectForKey:@"OutLanguage"];

 NSString *inLang=@"tr";
 NSString *textEscaped = [inputStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

 NSLog(@"textEscaped=%@",textEscaped);

 NSString *url = [NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?     key=AIzaSyAx5dSiKm1J-qkc0qKZpYnWhgFjYpoC84g&q=%@&source=%@&target=%@",textEscaped, inLang, outLang];

 NSLog(@"REQ : -%@-", url);
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
       }



 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

  NSLog(@"didReceiveData=%@",data);

  NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
  NSLog(@"OUTPUT : %@", result);
```

}

I receive `transfert d&#39;argent` but I expect `transfert d'argent`. This `d'` letter needs different kind of encoding I guess.

Comment: You probably don't want `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Try to figure out from documentation what it actually is, if you can't find it try UTF16.

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong. Give us an example of the bad data you are getting.

Comment: @mike Weller  for example i need to get " transfert d'argent " but i m getting something like" transfert d&#39; argent "  this d' letter need different kind of encoding i guess.

Answer (score 1):

`&#39;` is an html or xml entity. The data you are receiving has probably been xml encoded. You need to parse the response using a proper XML parser if this is the case. I'm guessing you are manually parsing out the data you want.

Comment: thanks for reply, i edited my codes in answer, i am parsing like that. Is it wrong way?